# Can't fill_parent width in landscape mode in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I an developing a simple call notifier.On call receive i showed a layout with two textviews,One have a simple text and other shows a caller id.

In **portrait mode** this is the output.
[image]

In landscape mode the problem is it cant fill_parent width.I also put the layout in layout-land folder.But can't able to load the layout-layout/activity.xml. 
[image]

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/incoming_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_top"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"        
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
   >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/incoming_call_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/incoming_call_label"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/incoming_call_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/contact_name"
        android:textSize="18sp"
    />
</LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

When phone is ringing(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) inside broadcast receiver i start a service which has this layout.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Is this a typo? `</LinearLayout`

Comment: The TextView with id = `"@+id/incoming_call_label"`, shouldn't have `android:layout_width="match_parent"` instead of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`?

Comment: Are you using `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the AndroidManifest.xml for your activity?

Comment: no i am not using configChanges in the  manifest

Comment: @TalhaQ: typo = typing error

Comment: @TalhaQ: moreover, you have a **useless outer container**. This is bad for performances. Other than this, `fill parent` has been deprecated in API level 8, in favor to `match_parent`

Comment: @DerGolem i have tried match_parent doesn't work for me

Comment: @DerGolem i have tried match_parent too but its still not working.When   rotate to the landscape mode it also doesn't loads the same name xml from layout-land

Comment: Have you read @fifarunnerr advice? You MUST declare orientation in your Manifest, in order to support orientation changes.

Comment: yeah i am not using configchanges in the manifest

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation" should be declared when you want to handle device's orientation change by yourself.If you dont declare then it will automatically loads layout-land vice versa.but in my case it is not doing similar

Answer (score 0):

Your text views are children of LinearLayout. Your Linear layout is has a layout_width of fill_parent but your TextViews have a layout_width of wrap_content if you change that to match_parent or fill_parent you should be able to fill_parent width.